# can't download user profile image from FIRStorage

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

when the user going to user profile tab he gets error and crash in the app and I gets error in the Xcode in the URLSession.shared.dataTask

```
func setupProfile(){

    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{

        logout()
    }else{

        usrnNameButton.isHidden = false
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        databaseRef.child("Users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value,
                                                                  with: { snapshot in

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            {


                if let profileImageuRL = dict["pic"] as? String
                {
                    let url = URL(string: profileImageuRL)
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.PP.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }

                    }).resume()
                }
                if let coverImageuRL = dict["CoverPic"] as? String
                {
                    let url = URL(string: coverImageuRL )
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.coverPic.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }

                    }).resume()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and this is my code to setup the user data
like that any one can help me
thank you

Comment: My advice for you, when you work with getting image from URL, use Kingfisher pod. It just saves you so much trouble, and he uses cache, so that next time you won't download again the same image, also it can show a placeholder image while downloading the one you need, and all this happens on the background thread. Just couldn't be better. Try it: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: hello thank you for replay

Comment: you can edit my code if you can

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8 • Swift 3

use this to download the image if you want

```
func downloadImage(url: URL) {
    print("Download Started")
    getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        print("Download Finished")
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png") {
          downloadImage(url: url)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hello thank you for replay now we fixed the error and the app still workin when we press in the profile tab but the profile image give me no a empty image {func setupProfile(){

```
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{

        logout()
    }else{
        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
         //userName.text = changeRequest?.displayName
        usrnNameButton.isHidden = false
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        databaseRef.child("Users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value,
                                                                  with: { snapshot in

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            {


                if let profileImageuRL = dict["pic"] as? String
                {

                    //let url = URL(string: profileImageuRL)

                        //self.downloadImage(url: url!)

                            //self.PP.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    //let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: profileImageuRL, cacheKey: profileImageuRL)
                    self.PP.kf.setImage(with: profileImageuRL as? Resource)

                }
                if let coverImageuRL = dict["CoverPic"] as? String
                {
                    self.coverPic.kf.setImage(with: coverImageuRL as? Resource)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

}

the profile tab image you can see it [https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4ENe.jpg][1]
thank you again

Comment: This line is wrong:
self.PP.kf.setImage(with: profileImageuRL as? Resource)
Should be 'self.PP.kf.setImage(with: URL(profileImageuRL)!)'

Comment: Also, make sure that your profileImageuRL is an actual link. Make a print and see what your dict["pic"] returns there?